# How to resolve org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session not started or terminated

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

I'm using Selenide 5.12.0 + Gradle + cucumber + JUnit + Java 11 for ui and api testing. I'm getting this exception for several tests in @After method only during remote run using Jenkins Browserstack plugin. I was not able to reproduce it locally.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session not started or terminated (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'f0743d4acdce', ip: '172.17.0.4', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.165-103.209.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4b..., userDataDir: C:\Windows\proxy\scoped_dir...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:2567}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 81.0.4044.129, webStorageEnabled: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 36ae701d218db21ad7ddc58919c...}
Session ID: 36ae701d218db21ad7ddc58919c10cb0b79f9360
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute(RemoteExecuteMethod.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteLogs.getRemoteEntries(RemoteLogs.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteLogs.get(RemoteLogs.java:77)
    at com.trgr.camden.tests.steps.hooks.ReportingHook.logBrowserConsole(ReportingHook.java:67)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor251.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:65)
    at cucumber.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:16)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:65)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:50)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:79)
    at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:24)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the stacktrace you provided it seems that you're trying to run your tests on

```
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.165-103.209.amzn1.x86_64'
```

however your driver capabilities contain the following:

```
platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS,
```

You need to update the capabilities per the platform you're trying to run your tests.